# Get data from each object in a forEach

Tags: javascript

I request the data of a movie, this returns all the cast members as objects in an array. I want to output their names (which are in the object in the response array).

By doing the code below I only return the first object because it does the `[0]` for each object.

```
angular.forEach(response.credits.cast, function(item){
  console.log (response.credits.cast[0].name)
})
```

If I remove the `[0]` the console.log returns `undefined`.

Comment: don't you want `item.name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming reponse.credits.cast is an array containing an object with key = 'name', this is what you're looking for.

[More documentation for forEach in angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

```
angular.forEach(response.credits.cast, function(item){
  console.log(item.name)
})
```

Comment: Ah so the response returns they array, but the items are the objects. makes sence!

Comment: Actually i was faster with my comment :D, but yes... no rep there

Answer (score 1):

Use `item.name`:

```
angular.forEach(response.credits.cast, function(item){
  console.log(item.name);
});
```